# After send value with mapDispatchToProps, redux Initial state is undefine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hello I am making login app used firebase google login. I want to save the user in the `user-reducer`.
The console shows user info from the firebase! but, It keeps shows undefined. I don't know why it shows like these.
Please advised!

[image]

```
[user-action ]
import { UserType } from './user.types';
export const login = ({ currentUser }) => ({
  type: UserType.USER_LOGIN,
  payload: currentUser,
});
```

**[user-types ]**

```
export const UserType = {
  USER_LOGIN: 'USER_LOGIN',
};
```

**[user-reducer]**

```
import { UserType } from './user.types';
const INITAIL_STATE = {
  user: [],
};
const userReducer = (state = INITAIL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UserType.USER_LOGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default userReducer;
```

**[Login.js]**

```
const Login = ({ googleLogin }) => {
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

  const getUser = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('doing...');
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setCurrentUser);
    resolve(currentUser);
    console.log(currentUser);
  });

  getUser
    .then(user => {
      googleLogin(user);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

 .... 

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onModal: () => dispatch(modalHandler()),
  googleLogin: currentUser => dispatch(login(currentUser)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Comment: Look better the picture, the USER_LOGIN action's payload is undefined and then you set `user: action.payload,`...

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is on `getUser`, you are resolving promise passing a state variable (currentUser) that may have been not setted (because `setCurrentUser` is async). I would suggest to modify you code in this way:

```
  const getUser = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('doing...');
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
      setCurrentUser(firebaseUser);
      resolve(firebaseUser);
      console.log(firebaseUser);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for point out! I am not familiar with Promise and Async. I think I should study more  thank you agian!

Comment: No problem, happy to help you. Have a nice coding =)

Answer (score 2):

```
export const login = ({ currentUser }) => ({
  type: UserType.USER_LOGIN,
  payload: currentUser,
});
```

should be -

```
export const login = (currentUser) => ({
  type: UserType.USER_LOGIN,
  payload: currentUser,
});
```

i.e no destructuring of `currentUser`

OR

```
googleLogin: currentUser => dispatch(login(currentUser))
```

should be

```
googleLogin: currentUser => dispatch(login({currentUser}))
```

Comment: oh!! Its works curly bracket make big change!  I should distinguish.  I will make note!  Really thank you!